# Using the youtube api, how do you upload a private video in ruby?

Tags: ruby, youtube-api

I can upload a video to YouTube using the Ruby api.  The problem is that I've asked for visibility => private, and the video is uploaded as public.  Other fields (title, description) are set correctly.  What am I missing?

```rb
    body = {
      :snippet => {
       :title => 'file upload',
       :category_id => 29,
       :description => 'description of first file upload'
      },
      :status => {
        :privacyStatus => "private"
      },
   }
    puts "body: ", body 
    r = youtube.insert_video('snippet,status', body, upload_source: fname, content_type:'video/mp4') do |result, err|
      puts "result: ", result
      puts "err: ", err
    end
```

Using google-api-client (0.30.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `google-api-client` gem expects underscore keys and then internally [translates `privacy_status` to `privacyStatus`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/b2eff01c7fd2c90292a094fbdfee3000beff87ad/generated/google/apis/youtube_v3/representations.rb#L1586).

That said, just change your code to:

```
body = {
  :snippet => {
    :title => 'file upload',
    :category_id => 29,
    :description => 'description of first file upload'
  },
  :status => {
    :privacy_status =>'private'
  }
}
```

Btw, you might want to consider using the "new" hash syntax which is less verbose:

```
body = {
  snippet: {
   title: 'file upload',
   category_id: 29,
   description: 'description of first file upload'
  },
  status: {
    privacy_status: 'private'
  }
}
```

Comment: There was some cut-and-paste going on in that sample; normally we do write with the newer syntax.